# Multiple voice triggers to start the same Activity on Glass and distinguish which one was used

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to use two different voice triggers to open the same activity, and inside this activity, decide what to do depending on which trigger was used.

Is this possible without adding an extra prompt? According to the docs, you have access to the `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS` only if a prompt is used.

So my question, is it possible to fire the same activity with more than one voice trigger, and  is there any way to know in code which trigger was used?

Comment: For the voice trigger you have to call from manifest It is not possible to trigger from code

Comment: I know, I just want to know in code which one was used if I declare more than one for the same activity

Comment: It will not be possible because voice trigger is just to invoke your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing what [@Ferdau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114174/366253) said, I found a better way with activity-alias and meta-data.

Add an activity that contains the first voice trigger to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.package.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/glass_first_trigger" />
</activity>
```

Then after that, add an activity-alias that contains the second trigger

```
<activity-alias
    android:name=".StartMainActivityWithAParameter"
    android:targetActivity="com.package.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
       android:resource="@xml/glass_second_trigger" />
</activity-alias>
```

Then, on code, you can read meta-data values and decide what to do:

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
int secondVoiceTrigger = activityInfo.metaData.getInt("com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger");
if(secondVoiceTrigger == R.xml.glass_second_trigger) {
      //TODO do different stuff
}
```

Comment: @fredy182 Just ran into a similar issue right now with something I'm working on. This solution looks great, I'm going to give it a shot now. Did you keep it like this in the end or did you end up refactoring it some other way?

Comment: @SMT I am using it like this, I also added an android:enabled attribute with a placeholder to enable/disable it per gradle flavor, so it will show up only for Glass and not for other platforms

Comment: @fredy182 awesome, that's a great idea. I put this in place yesterday and its working for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could actually just create a dummy `Activity` that just calls your main `Activity`...

```
Voice Trigger 1 -> MainActivity
Voice Trigger 2 -> DummyActivity -> MainActivity (with extra parameter)
```